# Code first Index & Key name in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using Code First approach and when I'm updating the database it create key/index names on sql database that I want to control. It creates key name P**K_dbo.Properties**, foreign key **FK_dbo.Properties_dbo.Documents_PropertyId** and Index name **PK_dbo.Properties**. How can I control what name the keys and index name should be.

How can I change the names?

I have added an image of the database and [Image of SQL Server](http://www.eflag.se/Code_first_Key.png)

My Code

```
public class Property
{
public int PropertyId { get; set; }

[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "VarChar")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string Title { get; set; }

public decimal Price { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }

public string Bedrooms { get; set; }

public string Bathrooms { get; set; }

public int Accommodate { get; set; }

public string Area { get; set; }

public int Type { get; set; }

public string Latitude { get; set; }

public string Longitude { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("PropertyId")]
public List<Amenity> Amenities { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("PropertyId")]
public List<Image> Images { get; set; }

public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}
```